# How to get the size of the body when meta tags is device-width

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mobile

I'm trying to get the height of the html content but I'm getting wrong result.
On the meta tags of the page I put this line:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1" />
```

For mobile device, and the content really fits the page, but the height of the body I get is the real height of the content and not it's height after it fits the viewport.